# Laravel : Polymorphic Relations + Accessor

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationships

I have a `Gallery` table that uses Polymorphic Relations so I can add `Images` and `Videos` to my gallery list.

Within the `Gallery` table I have a `galleryable_type` column that is populated with either `App\Video` or `App\Image`.

Is there a way for me to use an accessor (docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)) to change the value of `galleryable_type` to either `video` or `image` so I can use that column in JS to decide what gallery item type I'm dealing with?

I tried the following:

```
/**
 * Get and convert the makeable type.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
public function getMakeableTypeAttribute($value)
{
    return str_replace('app\\', '', strtolower($value));
}
```

But i end up with the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in Model.php line 838:
Class '' not found
```

I'm assuming that has to do with the accessor is being processed before the the polymorphic relationship but I'm not sure.

I can simply use the following in my controller:

```
foreach (Gallery::with('galleryable')->get() as &$gallery) {

    $gallery->galleryable_type = str_replace('app\\', '', strtolower($gallery->galleryable_type ));

}
```

But that seems like a dodgy way of doing things. Could a Laravel guru shed some light on the best way to tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found an interesting way to solve this issue.

In your models (`App\Video` and `App\Image`) you have to add:

```
protected $morphClass = 'video';  // 'image' for image class
```

then in your `register` method in service provider class add:

```
$aliasLoader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();

$aliasLoader->alias('video', \App\Video::class);
$aliasLoader->alias('image', \App\Image::class);
```

This will cause that you will write `image`, and `video` in `galleryable_type` in the database instead of class names.

So now you can easily get to this values with:

```
echo $model->galleryable_type;
```

Comment: Note: In Laravel 5.3 you should use [morphMap](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) instead.

Comment: Yes thats true in L5.3 we have morphMap howevere this answer was before the realese. I'll reedit my entry.